# FCM messages is not always delivered

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I push Firebase messages from PHP and they usually get the target Android app.

Nonetheless, and occasionally, a push message is not correctly delivered if the target Android mobile was inactive for some period of time. Then, if I open the app, the message is delivered immediately.

I read about the Doze status; the battery optimizations; etc. I don't want to bother the user to explicitly whitelist the app.

Thanks in advance !

PHP:

```
    private function sendFirebaseMessage($msg, $to_uid) {
       // getting firebase token ID
       $user_token_id = DB::getInstance()->getUserFirebaseTokenId($to_uid);
       
       #API access key from Google API's Console
       define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'A...7' );
       
       $fields = array
       (
                'to'    => $user_token_id,
                'data'  => $msg,
                "priority" => "high"
       );
       
       $headers = array
       (
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
       );
       #Send Reponse To FireBase Server
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
       $result = curl_exec($ch );
       curl_close( $ch );
       #Echo Result Of FireBase Server
       return $user_token_id . "]XXX[" . $result;
    }
```

Android/Java:

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        if (data.size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "StorableMessage data payload: " + data);

            if (data.containsKey("sender_id") &&
                    data.containsKey("sender_name") &&
                    data.containsKey("chat_topic")) {

                if (!ChatActivity.IsVisible) {

                    NotifsManager.showFirebaseNotif(this,
                            data.get("sender_name"),
                            data.get("sender_id"),
                            data.get("chat_topic"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the device is sleeping the messages are not delivered immediately, FCM works in this way.

In addition, if you add the REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission in the manifest, Google may block your app in the PLay Store if it does not comply with this : https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#exemption-cases